# Multibit trie implementation for ip lookup?

Tags: ip, lookup, trie

I have to implement multibit trie for IP lookup, but I am not able to implement multibit trie approach in C.

I have searched on many sites and found the method:-

```
 typedef struct node {
  struct node* table[256];
  Port_type port;
} Node;
Node* root[256];
```

Using the above code create a table for multibit and store the corresponding prefix in the array.

Does anybody know how to implement it in C or C++?